# Symfony 2.2.1 The ip address in request gets changed in Embedding Controllers

Tags: ip-address, render, embedding, controllers

Symfony 2.2.1 The ip address in request gets changed in Embedding Controllers. am in missing something. or is there any way to persist the clients ip address in the sub request. I am useing it in jquery template

**{{ render(controller("userBundle:user:checkuser", { 'userId' : 1 })) }}**

I check the ip address of the client in the main request and the in the above request

- got the correct ip in the main request (works fine)
- **but in the above request it gives the ip of the localhost while I need it to be of the client.**

Comment: Same here on SF 2.6. Must pass the IP through Twig by action parameter to prevent this behaviour. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [trusted proxies](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#trusted-proxies) to something like `['127.0.0.1']`. More informations on the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/trusting_proxies.html).